# Grab table value in html using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my code and it is inside table tags. It grabs data from my database and put it in table. My database also has auto increment column named id. What I want to do is when I click the cross icon that is in anchor, I will get the id for that column.

I tried putting the value of $row['id'] in an input type='hidden' but had no success with it.

Another idea I has is making an anchor id=".$row['id']." so every icon has a unique id pertaining to the id for that line. Though I don't if it is good. I can't check because I have no idea how to get an element's id so I can check. And I don't know how to pass this value to php.

```
<?php        
    $varSQL = "SELECT empNum, empName FROM tool.users";
    $result = mysql_query($varSQL, $Con);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['empNum']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['empName']."</td>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='icons/cross.ico' alt='Delete' height='16' width='16'></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The reason that your `$row['id']` didn't work is because in your `SELECT ... ` query you don't ask for the ID. add id to it as such: `SELECT id, empNum, empName FROM tool.users`

Comment: LoL that was stupid of me. Thanks for pinpointing this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data` attribute -

```
echo "<a href='#'><img src='icons/cross.ico' alt='Delete' data-rowid='" . $row['id'] . "' class='cross-icon' height='16' width='16'></a></td>";
```

Also added a `class` to be be used as selector(Not required for all cases). And with jquery access them when the icon is click -

```
$('.cross-icon').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('rowid');
})
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kke6297v/)

For `hidden` fields there is no need of jQuery -

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"
```

Or pass it as query string -

```
href='page-to-redirect.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]?>'
```

Comment: Sorry don't have much knowledge about jquery and javascript. I'm still learning. All I know is html and php. 

Can you explain how I can pass a value from html to jquery/javascript to php.

Is it really not possible to pass value from html to php directly?

Comment: @aozora Check the fiddle link

Comment: wow that's exactly what I wanted to do.

But how can I get the value of var id in the script?

I need to use its value in php because I'll make a query search using that id

Comment: You can use a hidden field or pass it as query string.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It seems the passing value via href is what I will be using. It is quite easy to use. I'll just get it via $_GET

Answer (score 0):

It is because you do not have `id` in your query. It should look like this:

```
SELECT id, empNum, empName FROM tool.users
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't notice that one

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do with this id? You can get the id using javascript (not PHP) and then using this value in an AJAX request or put this value into an input form and send it throw post but always you need to use JS not PHP.

Comment: I'm planning to grab the id so I can make a pop-up with the info of that column. I'm planning to select where id=id from table. And prompting the user what details will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php        
     $varSQL = "SELECT id, empNum, empName FROM tool.users";
     .........    
     echo "<td><a href='#'><img src='icons/cross.ico' data-rowid=$row['id'] alt='Delete' height='16' width='16'></a></td>";
     ........
```

Try this one.

In select query add `id` also and Get the `data-rowid` value for your further operations